# Exceptions from exceptions, does such a thing exist?

Tags: programming-languages

I am intrigued: In many languages there are both normal control flow and exceptions.

But I never saw "an exception from an exception" or "an exception from an exception from an exception". Why?

Why there are just two variants?

My guess is that an "exception from an exception" would be just another class of exceptions, but this needs to be elaborated further.

Comment: Have you read [the Wikipedia page on exception chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_chaining)?

Comment: Throwing an exception from an exception handler is totally possible and practiced.